# How do you get the tag id of post type

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a post type called resource, the taxonomy called category in this post type and then I have tags.. I need to get the ids of the tags in this post type.. this is what i have so far.. The problem with this is get_term_children() needs an id  and i don't want a specific id but all the ids.. these variables will be passed to my ajax.. Please help

```
$tag_id = array();
        $tag_resource = get_term_children( '', 'category' );
        foreach ( $tag_resource as $child_location ) {
                $tag_term = get_term_by( 'id', $child_location, 'post_tag' );
                $tag_id[] = $tag_term->term_id;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below function to get terms id

```
function get_terms_id_by_post_type( $taxonomies, $post_types ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT t.term_id from $wpdb->terms AS t INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS r ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts AS p ON p.ID = r.object_id WHERE p.post_type IN('" . join( "', '", $post_types ) . "') AND tt.taxonomy IN('" . join( "', '", $taxonomies ) . "') GROUP BY t.term_id");
    return $query;
}
```